# Responsive table adding margin in media query?

Tags: html, css

I created a semi responsive table that breaks down from 5 columns to 2 columns through a media query (it's a calendar that is broken down into individual days on mobile). It's almost working exactly how I want it to, but the table is slightly off center (appears to be about 10px to the right), when I'm expecting it to be centered because the table is in a div with margin:auto, which is inside of a container div with width:100%.

Here is the html:

```
<div id = "tbl-cont">
<div id = "tbl">
<table>
    <th colspan="5"><b>Week 1</b></th>
    <tr class = "days">
        <td><i>Day 1</i></td>
        <td><i>Day 2</i></td>
        <td><i>Day 3</i></td>
        <td><i>Day 4</i></td>
        <td><i>Day 5</i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class = "wk1">
    <td>Snatch 5x3 75%<br>Snatch pull 4x3 75%<br>Front squat 5x3 75%</td>
    <td>Pull ups 4x7<br>Bench 1x5 65%, 1x5 75%, 1x5* 85%<br>Dips 4x10<br>Barbell row 4x10</td>
    <td>Jerk 5x3 75%<br>OHP 1x5 65%, 1x5 75%, 1x5* 85%<br>Overhead squat 4x3</td>
    <td>Pull ups ladder<br>Dips ladder<br>Curls<br>Abs</td>
    <td>Clean & Jerk 5x3 75%<br>Clean pull 4x3 85%<br>Back squat 1x5 65%, 1x5 75%, 1x5* 85%</td>
    </tr>
    <th colspan="5"><b>Week 2</b></th>
    <tr class = "days">
        <td><i>Day 1</i></td>
        <td><i>Day 2</i></td>
        <td><i>Day 3</i></td>
        <td><i>Day 4</i></td>
        <td><i>Day 5</i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class = "wk2">
    <td>Snatch 5x2 80%<br>Snatch pull 4x2 80%<br>Front squat 5x2 85%</td>
    <td>Pull ups 4x5<br>Bench 1x5 65%, 1x5 75%, 1x5* 85%<br>Dips 4x8<br>Barbell row 4x10</td>
    <td>Jerk 5x2 85%<br>OHP 1x5 70%, 1x5 80%, 1x5* 90%<br>Overhead squat 4x2</td>
    <td>Pull ups ladder<br>Dips ladder<br>Curls<br>Abs</td>
    <td>Clean & Jerk 5x2 85%<br>Clean pull 4x2 90%<br>Back squat 1x5 70%, 1x5 80%, 1x5* 90%</td>
    </tr>
    <th colspan="5"><b>Week 3</b></th>
    <tr class = "days">
        <td><i>Day 1</i></td>
        <td><i>Day 2</i></td>
        <td><i>Day 3</i></td>
        <td><i>Day 4</i></td>
        <td><i>Day 5</i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class = "wk3">
    <td>Snatch 5x1 90%<br>Snatch pull 4x1 95%<br>Front squat 5x1 90%</td>
    <td>Pull ups 4x3<br>Bench 1x5 75%, 1x5 85%, 1x5* 95%<br>Dips 4x6<br>Barbell row 4x10</td>
    <td>Jerk 5x1 90%<br>OHP 1x5 75%, 1x5 85%, 1x5* 95%<br>Overhead squat 4x1</td>
    <td>Pull ups ladder<br>Dips ladder<br>Curls<br>Abs</td>
    <td>Clean & Jerk 5x1 90%<br>Clean pull 4x1 100%<br>Back squat 1x5 75%, 1x5 85%, 1x5* 95%</td>
    </tr>
    <th colspan="5"><b>Week 4</b></th>
    <tr class = "days">
        <td><i>Day 1</i></td>
        <td><i>Day 2</i></td>
        <td><i>Day 3</i></td>
        <td><i>Day 4</i></td>
        <td><i>Day 5</i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class = "wk4">
    <td>Snatch 5x1 60%<br>Snatch pull 4x1 60%<br>Front squat 5x1 60%</td>
    <td>Pull ups 4x6<br>Bench 1x5 40%, 1x5 50%, 1x5 60%<br>Dips 4x6<br>Barbell row 4x10</td>
    <td>Jerk 5x1 60%<br>OHP 1x5 40%, 1x5 50%, 1x5 60%<br>Overhead squat 4x1</td>
    <td>Pull ups ladder<br>Dips ladder<br>Curls<br>Abs</td>
    <td>Clean & Jerk 5x1 60%<br>Clean pull 4x1 60%<br>Back squat 1x5 40%, 1x5 50%, 1x5 60%</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
table {
    width: 90%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    }

td, th {
    width: 20%;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding-left: 1%;
    }

td {
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    Color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    letter-spacing: .01rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    }   
th {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    Color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    letter-spacing: .01rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    }

@media 
only screen and (max-width: 760px),
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px){

h2 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
        width: 90%;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        float: left;

    }
#tbl-cont {
    width:100%;
}

#tbl {
    /*width: 90%;*/
    max-width: 85%;
    min-width: 319px;
    margin: auto;
}

th {
    display: none;
    }
.days {
    display: none;
    }

td {
    padding-left: 50%;
    }
td:before {
    max-width:27%;
}
.wk1 td,.wk2 td,.wk3 td,.wk4 td {
    display: block;
}

.wk1 tr,.wk2 tr,.wk3 tr,.wk4 tr {
    margin-left:-30px;
    padding:0;
}
.wk1 td:before { 
        /* Now like a table header */
        position: absolute;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
        top: 6px;
        left: 6px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        /*white-space: nowrap;*/
        display:block;
    }
.wk2 td:before { 
        /* Now like a table header */
        position: absolute;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
        top: 6px;
        left: 6px; 
        padding-right: 10px;
        /*white-space: nowrap;*/
        display:block;
    }
.wk3 td:before { 
        /* Now like a table header */
        position: absolute;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
        top: 6px;
        left: 6px;
        padding-right: 10px;  
        /*white-space: nowrap;*/
        display:block;
    }
.wk4 td:before { 
        /* Now like a table header */
        position: absolute;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
        top: 6px;
        left: 6px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        /*white-space: nowrap;*/
        display:block;
    }

.wk1 td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Week 1 - Day 1"; }
.wk1 td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Week 1 - Day 2"; }
.wk1 td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Week 1 - Day 3"; }
.wk1 td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Week 1 - Day 4"; }
.wk1 td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Week 1 - Day 5"; }
.wk2 td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Week 2 - Day 1"; }
.wk2 td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Week 2 - Day 2"; }
.wk2 td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Week 2 - Day 3"; }
.wk2 td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Week 2 - Day 4"; }
.wk2 td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Week 2 - Day 5"; }
.wk3 td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Week 3 - Day 1"; }
.wk3 td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Week 3 - Day 2"; }
.wk3 td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Week 3 - Day 3"; }
.wk3 td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Week 3 - Day 4"; }
.wk3 td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Week 3 - Day 5"; }
.wk4 td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Week 4 - Day 1"; }
.wk4 td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Week 4 - Day 2"; }
.wk4 td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Week 4 - Day 3"; }
.wk4 td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Week 4 - Day 4"; }
.wk4 td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Week 4 - Day 5"; }
}
```

If anyone could let me know why the table is off center in the media query, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't look like the table id off center.

Comment: Please provide a _live_ example for cases such as this, so that not everyone who wants to have a quick look at the effect you are describing has to start a copy&paste orgy …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer: Your td tags are wider than the table.  Make the change below.

```
table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
    width: 100%;
...

td {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left:50%;
}
```

Long answer: Your CSS is getting overly complex. Your rule

```
table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
    width: 90%;
```

is complicating your layout.

So you have a div that contains your table, set to a width of 85% of the body. Then your table is 90% as wide as that. Then your tbody is 90% as wide as the table (shrinking). Then your tr is 90% as wide as your tbody (shrinking more) then your td ... at this point the width of your td tags have no logical relationship with the table, its just some arbitrary width - then 50% padding is added to the left of them.

I don't see why the tds' widths need to be (100% * 90% * 90% * 90% * 90%) + 50% or whatever the formula would be. Simplify!

Look into box-sizing, as that resolves the issue with the added padding expanding your tds.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. Yeah, I know I really need to work on simplifying it,  it's pretty sloppy right now.

Comment: I wouldn't normally think of doing a responsive table, but what you did is basically how one can make a responsive email template. :D

Answer (score 0):

## Hello

Dear, I hope you use bootstrap , right?

So, do you  want to make responsive table like this [demo](http://toticell.com/service_prp)
can flow this
or more help here  [HELP](https://www.facebook.com/mrana.2779)